# Where can I find the save destination path for a filefield? (via code)

Tags: 7, entities, files

I have an image file field and I am attempting to write a little script that will programmatically scan my nodes and save images found in the body of my node into an image file field entitled `field_post_image`

I've been looking at the default process of what Drupal 7 + Image Field does and the example on SO found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129559/attaching-files-to-nodes-programmatically-in-drupal-7

I figured the best practice would be to save the images to the same folder as the file field destination in an effort to keep my /sites/default/files clean of orphaned files etc.

I've looked at both [field_info_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.info.inc/function/field_info_field/7) and [field_info_instance](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.info.inc/function/field_info_instance/7) in the [Field Info API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.info.inc/group/field_info/7) and I can't seem to find the files destination (as configured in the Field UI)

Am I missing something and/or am I looking in the wrong place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's part of the instance settings of the file field, but it supports tokens. You want to call  [file_field_widget_uri($field, $instance)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--file--file.field.inc/function/file_field_widget_uri/7), that will give you a URI you can use to save the file.